# QPX Express - Arrival time formatting

Tags: python, date, formatting, google-qpx-express-api

I am trying to get the arrival time of the request body of the qpx Express API in Python. The response looks for example like this:

```
2016-07-10T22:35+02:00
```

What I would like to have is

```
Hour: 22
Minutes: 35
Timezone: +2
Year: 2016
Month: 07
Day: 10
```

is there a smooth and elegant way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance!!